# Swift iOS -Change background color of old cell when a new cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Before I begin it should be noted that if I don't change months or better yet after I manually select a cell, `didDeselectItem` does work fine.

I have a collectionView with tableData of dates (1-31, 1-30, or 1-28). When a user selects a day the background color of that cell changes to red. If the user goes to a different month the tableData is reset and cellForItem is fired again so all the cells background colors are set to UIColor.clear.

What I did to keep track of the initial selected day and it's month/year was create 3 variables that get initialized when `didSelectItem` is fired. When the user goes back to that month in `cellForItem` I check to see if the month and year match and if so change the background for that day. It works fine.

The problem is if I choose a different day the background color of that does change to red but the initial selected day also stays red. Because a cell was never actually selected (I just changed the color in cellForItem) didDeselectItem never fires to change the background color of the old cell.

**How can I get the initial day to change it's color when that new day is selected?**

```
// when a different month is shown some calculations are done to change these but those calculations aren't relevant to the question
var currentMonthIndex = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
var currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())

var selectedMonth = 0
var selectedYear = 0
var selectedDay = 0

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dayCell", for: indexPath) as! DayCell

    // clears the background color of all the cells when a new month is shown 
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor..clear

    if selectedMonth == currentMonthIndex && selectedYear == currentYear {

        // when coming back to the selected day/month/year this makes sure the selectedDay's background is still red 
        if indexPath.item == selectedDay {
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? DayCell else { return }

    cell.backgroundColor = .red

    selectedMonth = currentMonthIndex
    selectedDay = indexPath.item
    selectedYear = currentYear
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? DayCell else { return }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Here's an example if my question is unclear

A user chooses 1/1/2019 and the background of that day is now red. If the user goes to 2/2019 the tableData will have to change because there are only 28 days so all the cells for that month are clear. If they scroll back to 1/2019 the tableData changes again because there are now 31 days in the month so all the cells background color are changed to clear again. However since the month and year of 1/2019 matches what was initially selected, in `cellForItem` I can now automatically change the background color of 1/1 to red again. The thing is if I select 1/10 it's background does change to red but **1/1 still stays red**. I need 1/1 to change to clear once I select 1/10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and set the cell's selection state manually in `cellForItem`:

```
// when coming back to the selected day/month/year this makes sure the selectedDay's background is still red 
if indexPath.item == selectedDay {
    collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

That way the deselect method should get called and remove the background color for the previously selected cell.

Comment: @LanceSamaria Check my updated answer. You have to call the correct selection method instead of setting `isSelected`. Maybe you have to change the `scrollPosition` parameter for your needs.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works but isn't an ideal solution because if the cells aren't visible then the code won't run. In my situation since it's a calendar the cells will always be visible. If anyone has a better solution I'll choose it.

```
for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

I used it in didSelectItem before changing the background to red.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? DayCell else { return }

    for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = .red

    selectedMonth = currentMonthIndex
    selectedDay = indexPath.item
    selectedYear = currentYear
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **willDisplay** to set the colour and remove the colour logic from **cellForItemAt**.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? DayCell else { return }
    if selectedMonth == currentMonthIndex && selectedYear == currentYear {

        // when coming back to the selected day/month/year this makes sure the selectedDay's background is still red
        if indexPath.item == selectedDay {
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
            return
        }
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

On a separate issue, you really need to make your life easier with the dates and rethink your objects if you want to scale this.

Comment: hey thanks, I'll try it in a few. When you say "objects" I'm assuming "properties". What's the problem with the objects? Also I didn't add all the code. There's a lot more.

Comment: I don't want to get too much into it and distract from your question, but you can keep the date as a **Date** versus multiple int variables (look into date formatters and applying them into a Date extension). Then each **DayCell** could have a property **date** so it knows what day each cell is responsible for. Then you would just compare savedDate == cell.date. From there you can organise your properties and access levels better then your code allows you to

Comment: I understand exactly what you said and it makes sense. But since the cells get reused couldn't the date property your speaking of get corrupted?

Comment: I don't think they would do, since they would be tightly connected to your indexPath. Might be worth checking and if they do, you can have a refresh method that you call inside viewWillAppear which would ensure correct content is shown.

Comment: I'm using a subclass of UIView to create the calendar so there isn't a viewWillAppear only init(frame). But I do understand your point about those 3 properties, thanks for the insight. It works for now though so I'm happy with it. I do have 1 more question about your initial comment however (if you have the time). What did you mean by "if you want to scale this"? I'm a self taught programmer and outside of meet ups I never worked on a team. I understand scale at a startup/business level but in a situation like this how would I "scale" a calendar?

Comment: My bad on viewWillAppear, wrote without thinking, meant the willDisplay method from CollectionViewDelegate. Look into software architecture, design patterns and solid principles (especially separation of concerns), that's most of the theory around it, the rest is probably experience and knowledge sharing with other developers. In this case, you have a view for the calendar, with a collectionView. You could use a viewModel and inject it into the **DayCell**, so that the cell knows what to present and doesn't rely on ViewController or collectionView.

Comment: In normal circumstances I do use a model object for my cells, pass the data to a property in the cell, then call didSet to set everything. In this situation I used someone else's calendar and I had to make some adjustments to it. Other then not setting the MonthView delegate to weak and not keeping track of the selectedDate (my question) this calendar works really well and it's native and podless https://github.com/Akhilendra/calenderAppiOS . Thanks for the help and advice. Cheers!